# css direction rtl element order problem

Tags: html, css

I have this html:

```
<body style="direction: rtl">
    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <span>x:</span> <span>1</span>, 
        <span>y:</span> <span>2</span> |  
        <a>link1</a> | 
    </div>
    <a>link2</a>
</body>
```

With direction: ltr it displays:

```
x: 1, y: 2 | link1 | link2
```

But when I change it to rtl is shows:

```
link2 | x: 1, y: 2 | link1
```

while I would expect:

```
link2 | link1 | 2 :y ,1 :x
```

Is there a way to set css properties to achieve the expected result wihtout modifying the DOM elements structure (the types of the elements can be changed though)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
<body style="direction: rtl">
    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <span dir="rtl">x:</span> <span dir="rtl">1</span>, 
        <span dir="rtl">y:</span> <span dir="rtl">2</span> |  
        <a>link1</a> | 
    </div>
    <a>link2</a>
</body>
```

​This gave me what you wanted.

Useful links: http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/right-to-left.html and http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html

Comment: Thanks. I had my div style=inline. Once I changed it to inline block it worked. Again thank you.

Answer (score 2):

change the inline-block to inline-flex

```
<body style="direction: rtl">
    <div style="display:inline-flex">
        <span>x:</span> <span>1</span>, 
        <span>y:</span> <span>2</span> |  
        <a>link1</a> | 
    </div>
    <a>link2</a>
</body>
```

This will displays as you want in FF & Chrome, but not in IE.

Comment: For me it's working but I am scared to break other things.... Do I run any test to verify?